# Clojure - Do consumed lazy sequence elements stay in memory?

Tags: java, clojure

My application processes a potentially large text file line by line, my code is currently:

```lisp
(with-open [r (clojure.java.io/reader "large_text_file")]
  (doall
    (map #(process %) (line-seq r)))
```

In my code, will already processed lines stay in memory? If so, how do I avoid it?

And in general, do consumed lazy sequence elements stay in memory?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of [doall](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/doall) will retain the head of the seq and return it. The *whole* seq will reside in memory.

I assume you traverse the seq for *doing* side effects. Thats the purpose of doseq:

```
(with-open [r (clojure.java.io/reader "your_large_file.txt")]
  (doseq [l (line-seq r)]
    (println l)))
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends: the normal GC rules apply, as discussed [elsewhere on StackOverflow in great detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214258/holding-onto-the-head-of-a-sequence).

So, make sure you only reference elements as they flow through rather than holding the head of the sequence, and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to force the evaluation of a lazy sequence but you don't need to hold it, you can use dorun. It's the same as doall but returns nil and does not hold the whole sequence on memory.

Juan Manuel

Answer (score 0):

What does the return value of the function `process` yield? Will you end up building a large collection of something this way? I think you could process it with `doseq` which yields no value, unlike map.