# Clojure seq returning function vs direct 'def' of seq

Tags: clojure

Newbie Clojure question.  What are the pros and cons of the following two ways to implement/represent the Fibonacci sequence?  (In particular, is there anything to completely rule out one or the other as a bad idea.)

```
(ns clxp.fib
  (:gen-class))

; On the one hand, it seems more natural in code to have a function that
; returns 'a' Fibonacci sequence.
(defn fib-1
  "Returns an infinite sequence of Fibonnaci numbers."
  []
  (map first (iterate (fn [[a b]] [b (+ a b)]) [0 1])))

; > (take 10 (fib-1))
; (0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34)

; On the other hand, it seems more mathematically natural to define 'the'
; Fibonacci sequence once, and just refer to it.
(def fib-2
  "The infinite sequence of Fibonnaci numbers."
  (map first (iterate (fn [[a b]] [b (+ a b)]) [0 1])))

; > (take 10 fib-2)
; (0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34)
```

a) What are the pros and cons of these two approaches to defining an infinite sequence?  (I am aware that this is a somewhat special case in that this particular sequence requires no args to be provided - unlike, say, an infinite sequence of multiples of 'n', which I believe would require the first approach, in order to specify the value of 'n'.)

b) Is there any over-arching reason to prefer one of these implementations to the other?  (Memory consumption, applicability when used as an argument, etc.)

Comment: I'd define `fib-1` just to have it regardless, and then if you decide you need a non-garbage-collectable instance somewhere you can define `fib-2` in terms of `fib-1` as `(def fib-2 (fib-1))`.

Comment: Possibly duplicate to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214258/holding-onto-the-head-of-a-sequence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fib-2` is preferable in favor of time performance if its elements are looked up multiple times, because in a lazy seq they only need to be calculated one time.

Due to the global binding the seq is unlikely to ever become garbage collected, so if your program will step through a million fibonaccis to make some calculation once, even more so if it doesn't need to hold the seqs head, invoking `fib-1` in a local context is preferable in favor of space performance.

Comment: Just to clarify.  You are saying that `fib-1` might be better because it won't retain the seq longer than needed (potentially saving memory at the cost of recomputing the seq for different calls to `fib-1`).  But `fib-2` saves the recomputation at the expense of not (possibly never) garbage collecting the seq.  Did I understand right?

Comment: Especially if you are just iterating, every processed element of the seq can be garbage collected immediately.

Comment: This is where I am a bit fuzzy.  I had thought that all the elements (computed so far) in a seq are retained until the entire seq is garbage collected.  You seem to be saying this is wrong.

Comment: @Paul this is often referred to as 'holding the head', some functions will keep an entire sequence in memory, while others will only keep the section they are currently using. doall and dorun are examples of each kind.

Comment: If you are iterating, you usually don't hold onto the head. This means that after a step you leave the current sequence to the garbage collector but continue the next step with the `rest` of the current sequence. So with each step you are giving up the current head element of the sequence. If the seq is lazy, the heads are calculated on demand thus all that ever needs to be in memory is the current element. (Implementation varies slightly due to chunked seqs, but conceptually and for performance expectations this explanation holds)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  But in the case of the var `fib-2` won't this always hold on to (all of) the head? Otherwise a later use of `fib-2` wouldn't have the initial elements to iterate over?

Comment: Yes, correct. I should have made clear that I was referring to `fib-1`. This is why `fib-2` is  a bad idea if you want to just iterate once.

Comment: I've down-voted this answer for now, on the basis the the other answer indicates a issue with using `fib-2` instead of `fib-1`.  (I'll reconsider when I've had a chance to experiment to see what is going on.)

Comment: The issue is most likely a bug in Clojure/JVM. Also, I can't reproduce it. It doesn't affect the quality of this answer. Please refer to my comments on the other answer. Notice that you can't undo a downvote after some time.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your usage, and how critical it is not to have to recalculate fib seq multiple times. However, from my experiments below, I had issues with the def when using long sequences.

If you're going to be referring to a lot of elements, then you'll need to watch out for head retention, as Leon mentioned.

This can be illustrated as follows (these are extending a couple of examples from Clojure Programming):

```
(let [[t d] (split-with #(< % 10) (take 1e6 (fib-1)))]
  [(count d) (count t)])
=> OutOfMemoryError Java heap space

(let [[t d] (split-with #(< % 10) (take 1e6 (fib-1)))]
  [(count t) (count d)])
=> [7 999993]
```

Note, i had to change your implementation to use the initial vector `[0 1N]` to avoid `ArithmeticException integer overflow` when taking large sequences of fib numbers.

Interesting, changing to using fib-2 instead yields same OOM error for holding head case, but the non-head holding version breaks:

```
(let [[t d] (split-with #(< % 10) (take 1e6 fib-2))]
  [(count t) (count d)])
=> [7 270036]
```

The latter figure should be 999993.

The reason for the OOM in both cases is as stated in Clojure Programming:

> Since the last reference of t occurs before the processing of d, no
>   reference to the head of the range sequence is kept, and no memory
>   issues arise.

Comment: That's interesting.  I had expected differences in performance characteristics; I had not expected there could be any logical / computational difference to the result as a consequence of choosing one or the other!

Comment: I haven't tried to work out why it's going wrong, be interesting if anyone knows.

Comment: I can't reproduce the invalid result with `fib-2`.

Comment: very odd. mine is now OOM'ing even with a bigger jvm stack for fib-2, but not fib-1. I'm going to assume it's environmental, but it does look like function will lead to less memory issues.

Comment: Well, if you wish to keep a million fibonaccis in memory you simply need a lot of memory. Notice that the growth is exponential and the numbers around 1e6 have >200k digits each. For a program relying on a smaller sample only it might be a good strategy though.