# Using prn or println within a list comprehension for debugging

Tags: clojure

```clj
(defn f1 []
  (for [a [1 2]]
    a))
;user=>(f1)
;(1 2)

(defn f2 []
  (for [a [1 2]]
    (prn a)))
;user=>(f2)
;1
;2
;(nil nil)

(defn f3 []
  (for [a [1 2]]
    (prn a))
  'something-else)
;user=>(f3)
;something-else
```

Why does f3 not print 1 and 2 before printing 'something-else?

i.e. I expected and had assumed (wrongly) it would print the following:

```clj
; 1
; 2
; something-else
```

Came across this when using a for with a lot of code inside it and this played havoc with 
my attempt to use prn statements to trace the value of variables while debugging.
i.e. prn and println do not print out. I think it's only when the for block is not the
final form in its enclosing form, but i'm still not sure what's going on.

The point being that a side-effect such as `prn` or `println`, should not require to be in return value position for it to fire. So there's something deeper with list comprehensions that I don't understand.

A notion as I write this - maybe in `f3` the list comprehension is simply never evaluated, due to laziness? ... oh [censored].

Yes, that is indeed it:

```clj
(defn f4 []
  (doall
    (for [a [1 2]]
      (prn a)))
  'something-else)
user=> (f4)
;1
;2
;something-else
```

So, even though mostly solved, I will still post this question to consolidate the learning - would anyone care to post some examples of their own gotchas re. laziness.

Answer (score 1):

As you have documented here, the macro `for` is lazy, and doesn't execute until it has to.  You can force it by wrapping it in a `(vec ...)` form or a `doall`.

For debugging purposes especially, I like to use `spyx` and `forv` from [the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo) to avoid all of these gotchas:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn f5 []
  (forv [a [1 2]]
    (spyx a))
  (spy :returning :something-else))

(dotest
  (spyx (f5)))
```

With result:

```
-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.1    Java 14
-------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
a => 1
a => 2
:returning => :something-else
(f5) => :something-else

Ran 2 tests containing 1 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

So you can see printed nicely:

- the labeled value of `a` at each step of the `forv` loop.
- the return value of the function with a custom label
- the explicit value of the function call `(f5)`
- nothing anywhere is lazy
- `spy`, `spyx`, et al always return the value printed for further use
- a convenient unit test via `is=` confirms the output value.

There is a [nice template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template) that you can clone to get you started quickly.

You may also be interested in [with-result](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.200/api/tupelo.core#with-result), or just `doseq`. Don't forget [the Clojure CheatSheet](https://clojure.org/api/cheatsheet).

Comment: @Alan_Thompson  May I ask a follow up? - if I have a function the last form of which is a `for`, and I'm using it for side effects (to update an atom), since the for will return a list of its entire loop when run in the repl, is it reasonable to just add another form, a `nil`, after it, so that returns instead, then wrap the for in a doall to ensure it gets executed? This is to avoid unnecessary output when run in the repl. I was wondering if this is sensible style or not.

Comment: `with-result` looks nice.

Comment: If you don't want the result of the `for`, instead use a `doseq` which is like `for` but always returns `nil` and is only used for side effects.  `with-result` is useful when you want to return the final expression in a form or function, but also want to print out some stuff.

Comment: Thank you that's spot on. I had just now wrapped the `for` in a `doseq` (wrong) and was getting very confused with the return values it was generating - `doseq` *instead* of `for` has me back to sanity :)

Comment: In the doseq docs, what does it mean when it says "Does not retain
the head of the sequence"?

Comment: See here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214258/holding-onto-the-head-of-a-sequence, and also:  https://clojure.org/reference/lazy#_dont_hang_onto_your_head